# How to read corrupt disc

Tags: 12.04, dvd, cd

I have a corrupt mini DVD, which was used in a camcorder. It appears to be corrupt (did not play on camcorder) and won't open. I don't know what to try to fix it. Is there a way?

```
billy@marara-ubu:/media$ sudo mount -t udf -o ro /dev/sr0 /media/cd
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

billy@marara-ubu:/media$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o ro /dev/sr0 /media/cd
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

billy@marara-ubu:/media$ sudo cdrwtool -i -d /dev/sr0 
using device /dev/sr0
448KB internal buffer
setting write speed to 12x

DISC INFO:
        erasable : No
        border = 2
        Disc status = 1
        number of first track = 1
        number of sessions = 1
        number of tracks = 1
        status of last track = 3
        uru = 1
        did_v = 0
        dbc_v = 0
        disc type = 0
        disc_id = 0
        lead_in = 00:00:00 (0)
        lead_out = 00:00:00 (0)
        OPC entries = 0

TRACK INFO:

Track 1
        track_number = 1
        session_number = 1
        damage = 0
        copy = 0
        track_mode = 4
        Rt = 1
        blank = 1
        packet = 1
        fp = 0
        data_mode = 1
        lra_v = 0
        nwa_v = 0
        track_start = 0
        next_writable = 0
        last_recorded = 0
        free_blocks = 12272
        packet_size = 16
        track_size = 12272 (24544KB)

Track 2
        track_number = 2
        session_number = 1
        damage = 0
        copy = 0
        track_mode = 4
        Rt = 1
        blank = 1
        packet = 1
        fp = 0
        data_mode = 1
        lra_v = 0
        nwa_v = 0
        track_start = 12288
        next_writable = 12288
        last_recorded = 0
        free_blocks = 176
        packet_size = 16
        track_size = 176 (352KB)

Track 3
        track_number = 3
        session_number = 1
        damage = 1
        copy = 0
        track_mode = 4
        Rt = 0
        blank = 0
        packet = 1
        fp = 0
        data_mode = 1
        lra_v = 0
        nwa_v = 0
        track_start = 12480
        next_writable = 0
        last_recorded = 0
        free_blocks = 0
        packet_size = 16
        track_size = 701472 (1402944KB)
```

Comment: where do you get 'corrupt' out of these messages? there are 2 pointers in your text: syslog and dmesg|tail. What did those tell you?

Comment: @Rinzwind because the disc won't read on the device, I expect it is corrupt. And because I am unable to use dd to copy the binary data.

Comment: But you 1st need to mount it correctly ... the 1st 2 commands seem to use the wrong filesystem. `dd` comes after mounting ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I am pretty sure dd comes before mounting. I usually unmount things before copying them with dd. It works on the device level, copying the 0s and the 1s, and not even looking at anything as abstracted as a file. When that does not work, I expect the problem is a corrupt data disk (other disks work ok on the drive).

Comment: Any `dmesg`'s after `dd`? Would be very useful to know if there is or is not any.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `sudo dd if=/dev/cdrom of=dvd.img` where /dev/cdrom is your drive device path. This would create an image of the disc, trying to recover data in the process. Then you may try `testdisk` if the image that dd produces is garbage.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `/dev/cdrom`... maybe it is another issue. The cd drive does work fine, auto-mounting other CDs into the `/media` directory. I checked the device, which was `/dev/sr0` - and used that instead. I tried `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=cd.dat` with no joy - actually `dd` just hangs, and no data is copied to `cd.dat`. I tried this command on a working CD, after un-mounting it, and the command works. Thanks for your help... any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be under /dev/cdrom because it isn't mounted as one.

Do this: remove the mini-disc and run `mount`, put it in and run `mount` again. Any difference? If there is, you might be in luck. If that is the case, you should be able to `dd` the heck out of it.