# Problem mounting old UDF cds

Tags: mount, cd, udf

My father passed away last month, and I'm trying to recover some photos from some old cd-r's he left in his office. They appear to have been written using Roxio Easy CD-Creator. It burns both a udf and iso9660 portion of the disk.

I'm running the latest Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and when I insert the cd, I get the following error:

```
Unable to mount 692 MB Volume
Error mounting /dev/sr0 at /media/kris/disk1: Command-line `mount -t "udf" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8" "/dev/sr0" "/media/kris/disk1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock

I'm able to open the iso9660 portion with:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /media/kris/disk/
```

which returns:

```
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

and /media/kris/disk displays the files from Roxio which let you install a UDF reader on old windows 95/NT machines.

When I try to mount it with udf, I get the following:

```
sudo mount -t udf /dev/cdrom /media/kris/disk/
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: /dev/sr0: can't read superblock
```

dmesg returns the following:

```
[   61.555308] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[   95.733244] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   95.733254] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[   95.733259] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 Add. Sense: L-EC uncorrectable error
[   95.733265] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#24 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 28 9e 00 00 01 00
[   95.733268] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1352312
[   95.733324] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=338078, location=338078
[  102.152782] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#27 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  102.152790] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#27 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  102.152795] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#27 Add. Sense: L-EC uncorrectable error
[  102.152800] sr 1:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#27 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 05 27 9e 00 00 01 00
[  102.152804] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1351288
[  102.152844] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=337822, location=337822
[  277.770836] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[  328.362451] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[  337.322417] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[  481.091348] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[  661.191163] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[  822.936430] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[ 1309.910824] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[ 1354.450627] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
[ 1537.512308] UDF-fs: Failed to read VAT inode from the last recorded block (338076), retrying with the last block of the device (338078).
```

I have a stack of these things sitting here, and I'd really like to be able to get the data off of them. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to say sorry for your loss.

I found two possible answers, but they look similar to what you have already done, except the code it's a little different.  In the first found here:

[How to open UDF Volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359264/how-to-open-udf-volume)

the command looks like this:

```
sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom
```

This one seems simpler that what you have, the second looks a little more like your code, the second is found here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1095717

The code looks like this:

```
sudo mount -t iso9660,udf /dev/xxx /yyy/zzz
```

Where xxx is your DVD (you can check it with System -> Administration -> Disk utils) and /yyy/zzz is the place where you want the files to be mounted.

I might try:

sudo mount -t iso9660,udf /dev/sr0 /cdrom

To make it simpler.

Your last ditch effort might be to go to Kinkos, (if in the US) and rent one of their Windows machines ( I may be dating myself, but it seems like a few years ago they had a system like that.) and then open the disks there.

If you are sure they are photos, CVS has devices for opening picture CD's as well as printing the pics, and perhaps even Costco or Sams club can do the same.

I wish you all the luck on this, and you are not alone out there, my google searches brought up a lot of similar problems and answers.

Chris

Comment: Had to stop by Kinkos yesterday, they still have the windows workstations for rent, and they have the photo reading machines that allow you to put in our disk, and print the photos you want.

Answer (score 0):

Went through the same kinds of experiences with Mac discs.  Finally solved via [How to read corrupt disc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276845/how-to-read-corrupt-disc).  Command and output:

> sudo dd if=/dev/sr0 of=cd.img
>
> ```
> [sudo] password for glenn: 
> dd: error reading '/dev/sr0': Input/output error
> 197960+0 records in
> 197960+0 records out
> 101355520 bytes (101 MB, 97 MiB) copied, 39.3302 s, 2.6 MB/s
> ```

open the image and all jpegs recovered fine!